# 3D printing cylinder thickness and multiple tube copies

Tags: 3d-printing

Please help how to write multiple Tubes (say 10 tubes at $36^{\circ}) $ in rotated copies by `RotationTransform`  with 10 rotation copied units along with  hollow cylinder shell thickness =10 for 3D printing.

```
a = 50;
g1 = ParametricPlot3D[a {Cos[v], Sin [v],  v /2}, {v, 0,  2 Pi}, 
  Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Tube[5], Axes -> None, Boxed -> False]
g2 = ParametricPlot3D[{  a Cos[v],  a Sin [v],  w }, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {w,
    0, 152}, Mesh -> { 15, 12}]
Show[{g1, g2}]

Export[ "heli.stl", %]
```

EDIT1:

How to 3D-print a hollow torus or an Icosahedron to for a wall of given thickness?

```
RevolutionPlot3D[25{2 + Cos[u], Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2 Pi}, PlotStyle -> Thickness[1]?? ]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, I updated the code to fit the cylinder thickness for 3D printing

```
    a = 50;
g1 = Table[
   ParametricPlot3D[a {Cos[v], Sin[v], v/2 + n}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, 
    Mesh -> 20, PlotStyle -> Tube[5], Axes -> False, Boxed -> False, 
    Exclusions -> None, PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 152}}], {n, .25, 
    2.5, .25}];
g2 = ParametricPlot3D[{a Cos[v], a Sin[v], w}, {v, 0, 2 Pi}, {w, 0, 
    152}, Mesh -> {15, 12}, Boxed -> False, Axes -> False, PlotStyle -> Thickness[3]];
Show[{g1, g2}]
```

[image: fig1]

Code for 3D torus and halves of torus of finite thickness

```
{RevolutionPlot3D[{50 + 25*Cos[u], 25*Sin[u]}, {u, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[3]], 
 RevolutionPlot3D[{50 + 25*Cos[u], 25*Sin[u]}, {u, 0, Pi}, 
  PlotStyle -> Thickness[3]]}
```

[image: fig2]

Update for icosahedron

```
Graphics3D[{EdgeForm[{GrayLevel[0.25], Thickness[0.01]}], 
  PolyhedronData["Icosahedron", "GraphicsComplex"]}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image: fig3]

Comment: @AlexTournev Appreciate this. However  the cylinder has no PlotStyle, so after 3d printing we will have all helical rods falling out  apart due to no material continuity. How to specify connecting cylinder wall thickness using PlotStyle?

Comment: Ok, I updated the code to fit the cylinder thickness for 3D printing.

Comment: Ok thank you very much.Please indicate also (of given Thickness) printing faces of a hollow Icosahedron faces.I am getting data of vertices only.